# How to Find the control in repeater

Tags: c#, sql, repeater

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_slider" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_slider_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
 <cc:HtmlEditor ID="Htmleditor1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="550px" DialogButtonBarColor="Gray" DialogHeadingColor="Gray" DialogUnselectedTabColor="Gray" TabBackColor="Gray" Text='<%# Eval("banner_text")%>' DialogSelectedTabColor="Gray" EditorBorderColor="Gray" SelectedTabBackColor="Maroon" ToolbarColor="Silver" ToolstripBackgroundImage="Default" ButtonMouseOverColor="Gray" SelectedTabTextColor="WhiteSmoke" TabbarBackColor="Gainsboro" TabMouseOverColor="Gray"  DialogSelectedTabTextColor="White" />
</ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

how to get here text of html editor from  Repeater...

here      `Text='<%# Eval("banner_text")%>'`   are bound on repeater and how to get text on my c# code??

Comment: Find the control while iterating it through repeater. Look at here for sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422606/read-textbox-inside-a-repeater

Comment: i have need read HtmlEditor inside a repeater

Comment: Is this editor from Ajax control tool kit??

Comment: yes from editor from Ajax control tool kit

Comment: ok,i tried all way but how to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINNAY I GOT MY SOLLUTION.

```
protected void btnUpdate2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Button ib = (Button)sender;
                // string index = (ib.CommandName);
                RepeaterItem gr = (RepeaterItem)ib.NamingContainer;
                int index = gr.ItemIndex;

                property.banner_type = "Primary";
                property.active = Convert.ToBoolean(((CheckBox)rpt_slider.Items[index].FindControl("checkActive")).Checked);
                property.banner_index = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)rpt_slider.Items[index].FindControl("drop_IndexNo")).SelectedValue);
                property.banner_id = Convert.ToInt32(ib.CommandArgument);
                property.bottom_pos = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)rpt_slider.Items[index].FindControl("txtBPOS")).Text);
                property.right_pos = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)rpt_slider.Items[index].FindControl("txtRPOS")).Text);
                property.cr_user = Convert.ToInt32(Session["admin_id"]);
                property.cr_date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                property.banner_text = Convert.ToString(((HtmlEditor)rpt_slider.Items[index].FindControl("Htmleditor1")).Text);
                property.tag = 2;
                try
                {
                    int result = 0;
                    result = balss.banner_insert(property.banner_id, property.banner_type, "", "", property.active, property.banner_index, property.cr_user, property.cr_date, property.banner_text, property.bottom_pos, property.right_pos, property.tag);
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.up1.GetType(), "Script", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record Updated successfully.');</script>");

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "<script text='text/javascript'> alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
                }
                finally
                {
                }
                getdata();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(' " + ex.Message + "');</script>", false);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
            Response.Redirect("edit_banner");


        }
on button submit click i am used 
 property.banner_text = Convert.ToString(((HtmlEditor)rpt_slider.Items[index].FindControl("Htmleditor1")).Text);
for get value of html editor for repeater.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this... I 've tested your tool.. It works..
Add `using Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor;` as shown below.
Then you can access your editor from server side. You can use below method to find the Editor from your **repeater**. 
By using `editor.Text`, You can get Editor's Text

If you did't add the Reference DLL Please add it to your references. Otherwise you 'll get errors when you put `using Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor;

namespace ListDrop
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
            {
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                {
                    Editor editor= (Editor)item.FindControl("Editor1");
                    lblMessage.Text = editor.Text;


                }
            }
        }





    }
}
```

Comment: how to get text of html editor from Repeater... (not textbox)

Comment: `here  i am use ( <%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor" Assembly="Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor" %> )`   in aspx page

Comment: here `Editor editor= (Editor)item.FindControl("Editor1");`
editor not found on suggetion when i am write below code

Comment: You must add your reference like this as shown in the above answer  "using Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor;" And If you didn't add Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor.dll to your project (If you just copy and paste the code from another source) , You must add "Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor.dll" to your project references.

Comment: using Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor; add but Editor  not found

Comment: i am not copy paste code but there are changes in project that is my reqoirement .

Comment: So then there may be a reference issue. Try to clean and build your project and I 've showed how to get text from the editor inside the repeater. I can't say what is the issue exactly without looking at your code and project.

Comment: After adding "using Winthusiasm.HtmlEditor;" you still can't get the editor on your code. So it seems to be a reference problem. I 've no idea about how you added the reference to your project.